# Join on phone numbers in different formats

Tags: sql, join

I need an oracle SQL join on two tables on fields with phone numbers that have different formats.  The field on one table is the format 555-555-5555 and the other (555) 555-5555.

What is the syntax that could make this work?  The tables are small enough I could probably get by with dropping area codes and just focus on the last 4 digits.

Is it possible?  If I can't do a join I'm curious of the syntax for a simple compare such as:   `Where last4(phonenumber) = '4567'`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare the whole number, you can probably user regexp_replace to keep only the digits and then do the comparison:

```
where regexp_replace(phone_number,'\D','') = '55555551234';
```

`\D` matches non-digit character and removes them.

If last 4 digits will do, you can use substr:

```
where substr(phone_number,-4) = '1234';
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use any string function on your join (in the `ON` clause, it doesn't have to be straight forward columns, can be calculated values).
For example, following what you suggested, you can use SUBSTR to get the last four digits, and use this on your join:

```
SELECT * from tableA INNER JOIN tableB on SUBSTR(tableA.num,-4,4) = SUBSTR(tableAB,-4,4)
```